# Windows 10 taskbar notification (system tray) icons slowly lose resolution until they turn completely black

Tags: windows-10, taskbar, icons

Here's what my taskbar icons look like right now:

[image]

They actually look fine right after rebooting my computer, but then they get blurrier and blurrier, and then this is what they look like if I leave my computer on over night.

As you can see, it's only affected 4 of my icons for some reason.

They are:

- Google Drive
- JetBrains Toolbox
- ShareX (which actually came back to life right after I took this screenshot -- I'm guessing because the icon changed)
- And my own custom .net app

How can I fix this issue and prevent it from happening again?

---

The expanded icons are affected too:

[image]

They are:

- Logitech Gaming Software
- Bitcoin Armory
- Blizzard Battle.net

There's probably some commonality in how these icons are set programatically. Since my own program happens to be one of the infected, I can show you that code (C#):

```
_icon = new NotifyIcon(components)
{
    ContextMenuStrip = contextMenuStrip,
    Icon = new System.Drawing.Icon(Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetManifestResourceStream("DynDNS.mpen-avatar.ico")),
    Text = Program.GetIP(), 
    Visible = true,
};
```

Comment: While I know it's not cool to you, it's kinda cool to hear this happening. Is it _only_ the icons in the systray that are affected?

Comment: systray! that's the word I was looking for. Yes, just the systray, including the "popup" ones: https://i.imgur.com/M8A4PbD.png My taskbar is fine, desktop is fine, Explorer is fine

Comment: Whoa, that is freaky. It doesn't sound like something that could happen naturally, unless it's a problem in your screen, which would make it location-specific and not application-specific. Is it possible you have a program running that's doing this on purpose? (By the way, Microsoft claims "systray" is wrong and it should be "notification area", but everybody uses "systray" anyway. =P)

Comment: @TomerGodinger Well it's definitely not a screen-area thing. I've disabled some 3rd party Windows tweaker tools, maybe one of them was the culprit. We'll see if this happens again. None of them were supposed to touch systray icons though. Also just upgraded to Fall Creators Update so this is a very unscientific test :-)

Comment: "It's not supposed to" is code for "there's a bug in this program." I'm pretty sure one of those tools was the cause of this. If you don't see it happening again, you can try reactivating them for a while to see if it come back. Then your test will be more scientific. =)

Comment: @TomerGodinger Nope...still very much an issue after FCU and 3rd party tools disabled. Here you can see the icons starting to blur: https://i.imgur.com/PV4DTuY.png

Comment: I still think it's an intentional effect of *something*... You can try monitoring Windows API calls for [Shell_Notify](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762159%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396) with some utility (see [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2825960/wanted-winapi-calls-logger)) and check if anything accesses those icons, but first: what happens if you restart Explorer?